# Squared Question Mark Sign on CSV file read from Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, while-loop, upload, syntax-error

While doing upload csv file from UI that time validation doing whatever csv file the data should not be editable. On that time getting data mismatch with �. Uploading data appending with �. Input type as csv. Onchange of ID getting the csv file name. In index file UTF-8 metacharset is already there.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately your question is not very clear. Please review this FAQ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that other experts can help you.